# How can I perform a matrix interpolation from a linearly spaced axis to a logarithmically spaced axis?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, interpolation

Anyone know how can I interpole a energy spectrum matrix linearrly spaced to a matrix where one of the axis is logarithimically spaced instead of linearly spaced?

The size of my energy spectrum matrix is 64x165. The original x axis represents the energy variation in terms of directions and the original y axis represents the energy variation in terms of frequencies. Both vectors are spaced linearly (the same interval between each vector position). I want to interpolate this matrix to a 24x25 format where the x axis (directions) continues linearly spaced (now a vector with 24 positions instead of 64) but the y axis (frequency) is not linearly spaced anymore; it is a vector with different intervals between positions (the interval between the position 2 and the position 1 is smaller than the interval between the position 3 and the position 2 of this vector... and so on up to position 25).
It is important to point out that all vectors (including the new frequency logarithmically spaced vector) are known (I don't wanna to generate them).

I tried the function interp2 and griddata. Both functions showed the same result, but this result is completely different from the original spectrum (what I would not expect to happen since I just did an interpolation). Anyone could help? I'm using Matlab 2011 for Windows.

Small example:

```
freq_input=[0.038592 0.042451 0.046311 0.05017 0.054029 0.057888 0.061747 0.065607 0.069466 0.073325]; %Linearly spaced
dir_input=[0 45 90 135 180 225 270 315]; %Linearly spaced

matrix_input=[0.004 0.006 1.31E-06 0.011 0.032 0.0007 0.010 0.013 0.001 0.008
0.007 0.0147 3.95E-05 0.023 0.142 0.003 0.022 0.022 0.003 0.017
0.0122 0.0312 0.0012 0.0351 0.285 0.024 0.048 0.036 0.015 0.036
0.0154 0.0530 0.0185 0.0381 0.242 0.102 0.089 0.058 0.060 0.075
0.0148 0.0661 0.1209 0.0345 0.095 0.219 0.132 0.087 0.188 0.140
0.0111 0.0618 0.2232 0.0382 0.027 0.233 0.156 0.119 0.370 0.187
0.0069 0.0470 0.1547 0.0534 0.010 0.157 0.154 0.147 0.436 0.168
0.0041 0.0334 0.0627 0.0646 0.009 0.096 0.136 0.163 0.313 0.112]; %8 lines (directions) and 10 columns (frequencies)

freq_output=[0.412E-01 0.453E-01 0.498E-01 0.548E-01 0.603E-01]; %Logarithimically spaced
dir_output=[0 45 90 135 180 225 270 315]; %The same as dir_input
```

After did a meshgrid with the freq_input and dir_input vectors, and a meshgrid using freq_output and dir_output, I tried `interp2(freq_input,dir_input,matrix,freq_output,dir_output)` and `griddata(freq_input,dir_input,matrix,freq_output,dir_output)` and the results seems wrong.

Comment: Well, either transform your input data to logarithmic, or turn your output into linear for interpolation. Conversion from linear to logarithmic afterwards doesn't pose any conceptual or computational burden.

Comment: Or maybe I'm missing your point entirely. If you can put together a small dummy example (along the lines of a [mcve]), that would resolve ambiguities.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for your comment. I tried to improve my question. Now I put a small example of what I am trying to do. Maybe now you can understand better. I'm sorry for some formatting mistakes, I'm really new here...

Comment: Please try to [edit] your question and make that matrix more readable; at least edit it such that 8 lines are actually on 8 lines. You can see the result in the preview below your post while you're editing; you can keep working on it and only finish editing when you're happy with the result.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Now is better for your understanding?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I might not be able to respond on account of lacking time, but anybody else who might read your question will benefit greatly from a readable (and almost runnable) input.

Answer (score 0):

The course of action you described should work fine, so it's possible that you misinterpreted your results after interpolation when you said "*the result seems wrong*".

Here's what I mean, assuming your dummy data from the question:

```
% interpolate using griddata
matrix_output = griddata(freq_input,dir_input,matrix_input,freq_output.',dir_output);

% need 2d arrays later for scatter plotting the result
[freq_2d,dir_2d] = meshgrid(freq_output,dir_output);

figure;
% plot the original data
surf(freq_input,dir_input,matrix_input);
hold on;

scatter3(freq_2d(:),dir_2d(:),matrix_output(:),'rs');
```

The result shows the surface plot (based on the original input data) with red squares superimposed on it: the interpolated values

[image: result: red interpolated squares matching the input surface]

You can see that the linearly interpolated data values follow the bilinear surface drawn by `surf` perfectly (rotating the figure around in 3d makes this even more obvious). In other words, the interpolation and subsequent plotting is fine.